# Access textarea in one controller from another controller JavaFX

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have two controllers `FXMLDocumentController` and `FXMLOpenedCodeController`. I am reading the contents of a .txt file from `FXMLDocumentController` and I want that text to be placed in a textarea in the `FXMLOpenedCodeController`. The code is running and reading well from the `FXMLDocumentController` but when the window from `FXMLOpenedCodeController` is opened, the read contents from .txt contents is not visible in the textarea. My `system.out.println` shows that String mine has the contents but it is not showing in the textarea in `FXMLOpenedCodeController`. Please help anyone. Thank you.

FXMLDocumentController code

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private MenuItem open;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem about;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        open.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
                    public void handle (ActionEvent event){
                try {
                    showSingleFileChooser();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                    }            
        });
    }
    private void showSingleFileChooser() throws IOException {
        //Stage s = new Stage();        
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("ZEBRA file open...");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter exfil = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(exfil);
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
        if(selectedFile != null){
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXMLOpenedCode.fxml"));
            AnchorPane frame = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load();
            FXMLOpenedCodeController c = fxmlLoader.getController();
            //c.codeExecute = codeExecute;
            c.codeExecute.appendText(readFile(selectedFile));
            String mine;
            mine = readFile(selectedFile);
            //c.codeExecute.appendText(mine);
            System.out.println(mine);
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLOpenedCode.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage4.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage4.setTitle("Compile Code");
            stage4.setScene(scene);
            stage4.show();
        }   
    }

    private void newWindow() throws IOException{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLNew.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage3.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage3.setTitle("Enter code to run here");
        stage3.setScene(scene);
        stage3.show();
    }

    private String readFile(File selectedFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader buffRead = null;
        buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectedFile));
        String text;
        while((text = buffRead.readLine())!=null){
            content.append(text);
        }
        return content.toString();
    }
}
```

and in the `FXMLOpenedCodeController` there is a `public TextArea codeExecute;` I removed the `@FXML` and `private` so that the code works.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading `FXMLOpenedCode.fxml` twice. You put the text in the text area you get from loading it the first time, but then you display the UI you get from loading it the second time. So, obviously, you don't see the text as it is set to the wrong text area.

Just load the FXML file once:

```
if(selectedFile != null){
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXMLOpenedCode.fxml"));
    AnchorPane frame = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load();
    FXMLOpenedCodeController c = fxmlLoader.getController();
    //c.codeExecute = codeExecute;
    String mine;
    mine = readFile(selectedFile);
    c.codeExecute.appendText(mine);
    System.out.println(mine);

    Scene scene = new Scene(frame);
    stage4.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage4.setTitle("Compile Code");
    stage4.setScene(scene);
    stage4.show();
}
```